# SQL SUM on 'generated' column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

It's my task to count the total number of absent days for each employee.

i've written the following query

```
SELECT name
    ,surname
    ,absentdays
FROM (
    SELECT name
        ,surname
        ,DATEDIFF("d", fromdate, todate) AS absentdays
    FROM DiseaseReport D
        , Employees E
    WHERE E.number = D.empnumber
    )
```

Although this query works just fine it doesn't give me the 'TOTAL' amount of absent days per employee. Instead i get more rows (if applicable) per employee.

I tryed applying a SUM(absentdays) or GROUP BY 'name', but i'm guessing these are no options since the 'absentdays' column is generated.

Can you guys give me an alternative solution for this 'challenge'?

Comment: Not related to the question, but you should consider [switching to the ANSI 92 Explicit JOIN syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), the ANSI 89 syntax you are using is (as the name suggests) over 20 years out of date.

Comment: If this query "works just fine", you must be using a database other than MySQL, because MySQL DATEDIFF function takes two arguments (not three), and a derived table must be assigned an alias.

Comment: Well i guess things must have changed then, since i'm using Access 2013 and it works just fine.

Comment: I don't think anything's changed in MySQL. Your question makes no mention of "Access 2013" as the RDBMS. The only reference to an RDBMS in your question is the "mysql" tag, which refers to MySQL, not Access 2013. ref: [http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with applying a function (in your case, `sum`) to a "generated" column:

```
SELECT   name,
         surname,
         SUM(absentdays) AS total_absent_days
FROM     (SELECT name, 
                 surname,
                 DATEDIFF("d", fromdate, todate) AS absentdays
          FROM   DiseaseReport D, Employees E
          WHERE  E.number = D.empnumber
         )
GROUP BY name, surname
```

Answer (score 0):

Why have a redundant select statement when you can just use your inner select?

Just delete everything other than

```
SELECT name
    ,surname
    ,DATEDIFF("d", fromdate, todate) AS absentdays
FROM DiseaseReport D
    , Employees E
WHERE E.number = D.empnumber ;
```

Comment: This won't work. He's getting duplicate rows because the `DiseaseReport` table has many rows per employee.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(name,' ',surname) as fullName, sum(DATEDIFF("d", fromdate, todate)) as totalAbsendDays
FROM DiseaseReport D, Employees E
WHERE E.number = D.empnumber
GROUP BY fullName
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's generated shouldn't matter. Just make sure every column in your outer select is either in the group by clause or using an aggregate function (SUM, in this case)

```
SELECT name
    ,surname
    ,SUM(absentdays) 
FROM (
    SELECT name
        ,surname
         ,DATEDIFF("d", fromdate, todate) AS absentdays
    FROM DiseaseReport D
        , Employees E
    WHERE E.number = D.empnumber
    )
GROUP BY name, surname
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already a lot of answers. The best query to get the specified result from a **MySQL** database (as the question is tagged) would be something like this:

```
SELECT e.name
     , e.surname
     , SUM(DATEDIFF(d.todate,d.fromdate)) AS total_absentdays
  FROM Employees e
  JOIN DiseaseReport d
    ON d.empnumber = e.number
 GROUP BY e.surname, e.name
```

This will return only rows from Employees that have at least one row in the DiseaseReport table. If you want to also include employees that have zero absences, add the keyword `LEFT` before `JOIN` to make it an outer join operation, and to return a zero in place of a NULL, wrap the total_absentdays expression in a `IFNULL( expr, 0)`.

This same basic query will work in databases other than **MySQL** (e.g. Oracle and SQL Server), with the exception of the expression to derive the "difference in days", that is, the **MySQL** `DATEDIFF()` function will need to be replaced with syntax appropriate for each database.

To get an equivalent result from **SQL Server**, the DATEDIFF function takes three arguments, with the earlier date before the later day, to get a non-negative value:

```
SELECT e.name
     , e.surname
     , SUM(DATEDIFF('DAY',d.fromdate,d.todate)) AS total_absentdays
  FROM Employees e
  JOIN DiseaseReport d
    ON d.empnumber = e.number
 GROUP BY e.surname, e.name
 ORDER BY e.surname, e.name
```

---

NOTES:

There's no need for an inline view to get the specified result.

Ditch the old school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the JOIN keyword instead, and relocate the join predicates to an ON clause.

The MySQL DATEDIFF() function takes two arguments, and returns the number of integer days between the two date values. To have the function return a non-negative integer value, the "later" date should be the first argument, the "earlier" date should be the second.

Also, best practice is to fully qualify all column references with the alias assigned to the table. This makes it easier for the reader to read and decipher the SQL... e.g. the reader doesn't know if the 'name' column coming from the DiseaseReport or the Employees.

With MySQL, the GROUP BY clause implies an ORDER BY clause. If you want the results in a different order, then add an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: If i try your first example within Access 2013 i'm getting the message 'Component FROM contains syntax error'

Comment: @John Dane: Relational databases differ in the syntax accepted. I posted syntax valid for MySQL, since your question is marked with the "mysql" tag, a reference to MySQL, not Access 2013. ref: [http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info).

Answer (score 0):

There could well be multiple employees with the same name+surname, 
so use e.number for the distinction:

```
SELECT e.surname
    ,e.name
    ,e.number
    ,SUM(DATEDIFF("d", d.fromdate, d.todate)) AS _sickdays 
FROM Employees     AS e
JOIN DiseaseReport AS d ON d.empnumber = e.number
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY surname, name, number
```